# Microsoft Graph API 403 for Guest on Drive List Children

Tags: typescript, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-files

I'm having a problem using Microsoft Graph for external users (i.e. guests invited to the tenant) in my project.

- Angular 8 application for the front end
- NestJs for the backend
- Delegated permissions added to the App Registration for Sites.ReadWrite.All (Admin Consent is given)

The Token is passed to the backend application where I make another call to the Microsoft auth endpoint to get another access_token "on behalf of the user" which I then use to create my graph client.

```
async getClient(request: Request): Promise<Client> {
const accessToken = await this.tokenProvider.getAccessTokenOnBehalfOfUser(request);

return Client.init({
  authProvider: done => {
    done(null, accessToken);
  },
});
}

async getAccessTokenOnBehalfOfUser(request: Request): Promise<string> {
const loginToken = request.headers['authorization'].replace('Bearer ', '');

const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' };

const body = new URLSearchParams();
body.set('grant_type', 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer');
body.set('client_id', process.env.OIDC_CLIENT_ID);
body.set('client_secret', process.env.OIDC_CLIENT_SECRET);
body.set('scope', 'openid');
body.set('assertion', loginToken);
body.set('requested_token_use', 'on_behalf_of');

const response = await this.httpService
  .post(`https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.OIDC_TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token`, body, {
    headers: headers,
  })
  .toPromise();

return response.data['access_token'];
}



async getFilesByFolerPath(folderPath: string, client: Client) {
    try {
      return await client.api(`/${SITES}/${this.siteId}/drive/${ROOT}:/${folderPath}:/${CHILDREN}?${EXPAND_LISTITEM}`).get();
    } catch (error) {
      const x = error;
    }
  }
```

Problem:

Here's the weird part. When I am logged in as an external user, I get a `403`  error response from `getFilesByFolderPath`. However, when I go to the SharePoint site it's trying to reach separately, I have access and can see all the documents, files, etc. After I have opened SharePoint, the call to Microsoft Graph works.

*NOTE: I even log into SharePoint on a separate browser (even inside a different VM) just to make sure it's not caching a token.)*

However, after a period of time (~1 hour), the Graph call stops working again. I then need to go to SharePoint and refresh any page for it to restore access.

For internal AAD users, this call works 100% of the time. Looking at my access token it has all the required permissions etc.

Wondering has anyone any ideas on this?

[image]

Error thrown by the Graph doesn't have much information in it:

[image]

**Update**

I ran the request in postman and the response headers had this error code and details:

> X-MSDAVEXT_Error →917656; Access denied.
>
> Before opening files in this location, you must first browse to the web site and select the option to login automatically.

There must be a setting in the Admin portal for Office365/SharePoint that can help with this situation for External members to the AAD.